# WordPress video mass import

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress website a video theme loaded.
i have about 1000 video on my computer that i need to upload them into wordpress media ( do a title and thumbnail for each video uploaded )

my server and videos are locally on different computers

i have search a lot for a plugin that allows to  read a directory and upload the videos and generate a title and thumbnail for them.

have anyone done this before? which plugin did you use what plugin is available to buy

because if i need to upload each video it will take me a whole year.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bro the easiest way is to copy the videos to the upload directory and use this plugin so that all the thumbnails are generated properly.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

hope it will solve your problem

Comment: greetings Exprator,thanks for your reply 
but how can i auto post posts for all videos in my directory

Comment: did not get that what you meant, can you describe what you actually want to do.

Comment: after copying the videos
and re-generating the thumbnails i want users to see the posts for every video uploaded.. when uploaded no one can see the videos unless i post it in a post. is there a way to mass post with the video title auto generated